# Planet with hexagons with either magic or technology

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, magic, space-exploration

I read a good book a while ago and can't remember the title.

It is the story of people stuck on a planet made of hexagons, where the level of technology is set depending on the type of hexagon. Some have high-level tech, others have magic, and some have both or neither. Magic can't be used on tech-only hexagons, and vice versa.

I also remember that at some point the heroes get captured by a magical tribe, and one of the women ends up being forced to touch a pyramid that transforms her partly into a donkey.

I also think that the planet was alien-made, and the hero ends up realising that he is not human at all but alien. He is just so old that he forgot part of his memory.

I don't think I mixed up two different books in there, but I might have...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135337/science-fiction-looking-for-an-old-book (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 13):

This is Jack L. Chalker's [*Well World* series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?1809) (1977-2000). Specifically, I believe it is *Exiles at the Well of Souls*, which has the sequel *Quest for the Well of Souls*. (As for the rest of the the list I linked to, *Midnight* is a standalone, and *Return* & *Twilight* tell of a deliberate and more organized return on the part of the characters from *Exiles* and *Quest*.)

Your memory of the details is not wrong.

Answer (score 10):

How about [*Well World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_World) (1977-2000) by Jack L. Chalker.  Not a 100% match for some of your later details, but has the hexagons of different tech levels.

It is a series of books.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the right series. Too bad the question has spoilers!

Comment: @Erik Noren I do not recall that the spoilers are really accurate.  But I read the series at least 10-15 years ago, so my memory is somewhat faint on the topic.