# Title of a book I read in the 1980s, human scientists transformed into aliens in a world-zoo

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I am looking for the title and author of a book I read in the early 1980s.  It was about a team of scientists who find a mysterious abandoned alien gateway and it's their task to find out what's on the other side.  They go through the gateway, and each member is transformed into a different type of alien. These aliens are kept on a world that is like a huge zoo.  The world is separated into huge octogons, and a different species is housed in each octogon.  I don't remember much about the different alien species, but one is a species in which the females become incapacitated during their menstrual cycles. Over the course of the book, the human/alien in that world invents birth control so that the females revolt and gain power. I don't remember how it ends, other than the scientists find a way to communicate with each other and escape. Thank you so much for any help with this!!

Comment: A possible answer from a similar question here: It looks like it might be Jack L. Chalker's Well World series.  So it's hexagon, instead of octogon. Does that jive with everyone's memory? Which book would it be?

Comment: semi-duplicate (same series) of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135337/science-fiction-looking-for-an-old-book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *[Twilight at the Well of Souls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_at_the_Well_of_Souls)*, the fifth book in the [Well World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_World_series) series by Jack Chalker.

> “When you go into desperate heat every six weeks, there’s not much you
>   can do.”
>         “Uh huh,” the computer agreed. “And so what do we have to introduce to produce a revolution the way we want it—on schedule, on
>   time, just waiting for the load of new Entries?”
>
> “You’d have to kill off all the males,” she responded, then stopped. “No. That wouldn’t work. That would only put us all in
>   unending heat.”
>
> “What you need,” Obie continued, “is something that will keep the Time from coming. You need the one thing a race that reproduces so
>   slowly it still has females in heat would never consider, not even the
>   most intellectual of them. You need a birth-control device—or, rather,
>   a birth-control chemical, something that would fool your body into
>   thinking it wasn’t the Time.”

[image]

Comment: [Obie?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-24/obie)

Comment: YES YES YES! Oh my gosh. I've been wondering the answer to this question for decades, and you've answered it in a matter of minutes. *deep bow*

Comment: @Adamant -  What about him/it?

Comment: @Valorum - From your quote.

Comment: @tlinse - It was a very good description and your comment above was immensely helpful.

Comment: @Adamant - Oh, ok. No, different Obie. And you should know by now that I don't read half of what I post.